# How to let Newtonsoft.Json allow Json DateTime conversion with Timezone info?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, iso, json.net

I have a MVC3 project that manages events' dates. The problem is that when I write a JsonResult

```
   //...
   var StartDate=new DateTime(1999,12,10,2,3,40);
   return Json(StartDate,JsonBehavior.AllowGet);
```

the response's body format is something similar to

```
"StartDate":"\/Date(1374962232247)\/"
```

This result is giving me a date in the last day according to the server timezone, Instead of returning something like

```
 "StartDate":"\/Date(1374962232247-0600)\/"
```

which contains some server timezone info!
I can't follow the [SHanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)(like it but It seems not appropriated)! 
So, can someone tell me how to let Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6 packages convert Json DateTime with Timezone info?
Kind Regards

Comment: Maybe I would have asked "how to let Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6 packages ALLOW the Json DateTime conversion with Timezone info? "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this [link](https://gist.github.com/jpoehls/1424538) should help you with setting up MVC3 project working with Newtonsoft Json Serializer. For ISO date time formatter you should change the following lines in the `JsonNetResult` constructor.

```
public JsonNetResult()
{
    Formatting = Formatting.None;
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
    SerializerSettings = settings;
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet;
}
```

You have to derive your controllers from BaseController to use the custom result.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for your answer...where is that JsonNetResult located? and I'm now using a BaseController from which all controllers inherit: Are you talking about this kind of controller or what? And the link you provided seems breaken